# Type and mechanism of piping fitting

Tags: pressure, piping

What is the type of and principle of operation of the fitting connector circled in this photo:

[image]

There are a few other similar joints depicted.

It looks like this connector is tightened "circumferentially" as a hoop, possibly / probably over the top of the mating flanges of the two fittings. So that makes the fitting ends universal but its *not obvious how it would provide reaction against the pressure at the joint*.

(Contrast to the bolted flanges just below the circled area - its more obvious that they press the fittings together, maybe with a gasket, which would resist internal pressure forcing the joint apart).

---

Note: photo snippet from [What is this plumbing apparatus?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15736/what-is-this-plumbing-apparatus)

Answer (score 2):

The flange on the pipes are beveled and the groove in the clamp is V shaped. There is also a seal between the 2 pipes.

As the clamp is screwed down it will force the 2 ends together.

The dimensions are such that the clamp will not bottom out without providing enough pressure to ensure water tightness.

Answer (score 1):

These are rigid grooved clamps and are frequently used in fire protection and sprinkler systems plumbing because they allow fast replacement of valves.

Here is one 2/12 inch example.

https://m.made-in-china.com/product/2-1-2-Size-Grooved-Rigid-Coupling-and-Plumbing-Clamps-for-Fire-Protection-Piping-705008162.html